# Models.py Issue (Keys)

Tags: python, mysql, django, pycharm

I'm trying to make a basic web application for as a small project and I'm facing an issue where whenever I use any type of relationship between 2 attributes. 
Like when I try to pull some data from another table, it gets displayed as "Person object(1)" or "project object(1)".
How do I ensure that this doesn't happen and the name of the person and the name of the project shows up?
Im also willing to accept any sort of help with improving my database codes..
Thank you in advance.

Attached below is the source code.

When I try to pull some data from another table, it gets displayed as "Person object(1)" or "project object(1)".
    How do I ensure that this doesn't happen and the name of the person and the name of the project shows up?

from django.db import models

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.contrib import admin


class Project(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICE = (
       ('Work Assigned', 'Work Assigned'),
       ('Work in Progress', 'Work in Progress'),
       ('Testing', 'Testing'),
    )
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status_of_the_project = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    finish_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    supporting_documents = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    Admin_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


def __str__(self):
    return self.project_name


class Meta:
        verbose_name = "List of Projects"
        verbose_name_plural = "List of Projects"


class Person(models.Model):
    PERSON_TYPE = (
        ('Admin', 'Admin'),
        ('Project Manager', 'Project Manager'),
        ('Technician', 'Technician'),
        ('Tester', 'Tester')
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_person')
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, null=True, related_name='people')
    mail_id = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    person_type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=PERSON_TYPE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User-Project Assignment"
        verbose_name_plural = "User-Project Assignment"


class Bug(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICE = (
        ('Unassigned', 'Unassigned'),
        ('Assigned', 'Assigned'),
        ('Testing', 'Testing'),
        ('Tested', 'tested'),
        ('Fixed', 'Fixed')
    )
    SITUATION_TYPE = (
        ('Bug', 'Bug'),
        ('Issue', 'Issue'),
        ('Enhancement', 'Enhancement'),
        ('Not an issue or bug', 'Not an issue or bug'),
        ('Fixed', 'Fixed')
    )

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    issue_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    situation_type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=SITUATION_TYPE)
    basic_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    detailed_description = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE)
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=False)
    reported_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    reporters_mail_id = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    reported_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    deadline_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    supporting_documents_by_reporter = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    project_managers_comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
    supporting_documents_by_project_manager = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    technicians_comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
    supporting_documents_by_technician = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    testers_comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
    supporting_documents_by_tester = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_admin', default=False)

    def __str__(self):
            return '{} ({})  [{} {}]'.format(self.project, self.situation_type, self.status, self.issue_title)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Project-Tasks"
        verbose_name_plural = "Project-Tasks"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `Project` class's `__str__` method is not correctly indented. This is causing you to see `Project object(1)`.

In the case of `Person object(1)`, you have not implemented the `__str__` method for this class.

In any django model class definition you typically want to implement and override the `django.db.models.model` `__str__` method as you have done in your `Bug` class.

This `__str__` method dictates how the model is rendered when either printed to a stream such as `stdout` or in this case I assume rendered by Djangos Templating engine.

A typical use case could be as follows (shown as in python3.6 shell):

```
>>> class MyClass:
>>>     def __init__(self, x):
>>>         self.x = x
>>> 
>>>     def __str__(self):
>>>         # a string formatted with this instances x value
>>>         return "{}".format(self.x)
>>> 
>>> my_instance = MyClass(1)
>>> print(my_instance)
>>> 1
```

Please note the older `__unicode__` method. This method operates in the same way as `__str__` however is used in python 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

could be that you also need to add

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s" % (self. project_name)
```

to your Project class (similar to "__str__" function). And then the same for Person.